# Update IONIC not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I would like some assistance with IONIC. My update is not working. I have tried the following command:

```
ionic lib update
```

The result of this command is as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aG7tU.png

I believe the problem lies in the fact I am not in the www directory. I would like to know how to locate the www directory.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to be in `www` folder, if you want to update ionic libraries of your project then go to your ionic project folder and run 
`ionic lib update` 
But if you want to update your ionic package then run this command anywhere 
`sudo npm update -g ionic` 
In case of windows os `npm update -g ionic`

Comment: i want to update in system my ionic and when create new project to be last updated, is that this second command?

Comment: When enter that command, report message is:
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @RS92 ,  i assume you are running windows, run without sudo,only  `npm update -g ionic`

Comment: You ionic has been updated. `1.6.4` is latest version, as you can see in your ionic info, you have same version. Most latest one.

Comment: @RS92 Compare your image which you put in question with latest one.
Your older version were: `ionic-cli:1.6.1` and `ionic app lib version: 0.3.3`. Now they are 1.6.4 and 0.3.8

Comment: OK i think thats latest version, but i can't find on official website

Comment: ok thanks look this https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-lib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md ,here is 0.4.0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88624/discussion-between-mudasser-ajaz-and-rs92).